How to Minimally Modify a Non-Negative Matrix to Reduce Its Rank to $N-1$ While Maintaining Non-Negativity?
I am facing a challenge where I have an $N \times N$ matrix $A$, with all entries non-negative. Theoretically, I know the rank of this matrix should be $N-1$, but due to observational errors, the actual measured matrix has a rank of $N$. Now, I need to construct a new matrix $A'$ that has a rank of $N-1$ and ensures all entries remain non-negative.
My goal is to minimize the difference between the original matrix $A$ and the new matrix $A'$, specifically solving the following optimization problem:
$$
\min_{A'} \|A - A'\|
$$
with the constraints:
$$
\text{rank}(A') = N-1
$$
$$
A' \geq 0
$$
I know for matrices that are not required to be non-negative, I just need to perform SVD on A and discard the smallest singular value to reduce the rank. However, this approach can introduce negative entries, which is unsuitable for my case.
Is there a method or mathematical technique to solve this particular problem that both reduces the matrix rank and ensures all elements are non-negative? Are there specific optimization algorithms or approaches recommended for this type of issue?
Thank you very much for your help!
